# Is it possible to change the contents of the commentted part of the commit message when adding a commit in git?

Tags: git, version-control

I don't want to change the actual commit message, I want to change the template for the commented text displayed while entering the commit message.

For example this:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch add_mssql
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   csv/jobdetails.csv
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   db/test.db
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       Person.js
#       README.MD
#       get_supervisorjobs.js
#       loadmsqlviews.js
#       mssql/
#       results.html
#       results.js
#       supervisorsNpositions.js
```

Comment: What commented text? Can you share an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can [change the default commit message template](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) with `git config --global commit.template ~/.gitmessage.txt`. (Just make sure you have a `.gitmessage.txt` file and that the contents are what you'd like the default to be.)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to change default commit messages is to install a `prepare-commit-msg` git hook. This allows you to provide a script to modify the commit message in different ways depending on the situation (whether this is a new commit, a merge commit, and amended commit etc.).

See prepare-commit-msg under `git hooks --help`.